# NPM install with git clone resulting in error

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to build from source from a git clone rather than doing `npm install package-name`.
This is the syntax I'm using: `git clone package-name && cd package-name && npm i` But I get some error shown below.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts.git && cd lightweight-charts && npm i
Cloning into 'lightweight-charts'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 21225, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (230/230), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (167/167), done.
remote: Total 21225 (delta 166), reused 102 (delta 60), pack-reused 20995
Receiving objects: 100% (21225/21225), 13.90 MiB | 448.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16144/16144), done.
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: eslint-plugin-jsdoc@37.9.7
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: eslint-plugin-jsdoc@37.9.7
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^12 || ^14 || ^16 || ^17"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.5.5","node":"v18.3.0"}

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

`$ node --version v18.3.0`
I should have the node version required `^17`

running `npm install lightweight-charts` works no problem but I don't get the latest git commits.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: yes but how do you solve it? @jonrsharpe

Comment: What the problem is also provides a pretty strong hint as to how to go about solving it, no? Please [edit] with your understanding of what's happening and what solutions you've tried so far.

Comment: Nope. I'm an absolute beginner here. 
I have no idea why this error because I have the latest node/npm

Comment: _"I have the latest node/npm"_ - that _is_ why the error, `Required: {"node":"^12 || ^14 || ^16 || ^17"}` but `Actual:   {"npm":"8.5.5","node":"v18.3.0"}`.

Comment: so I have to downgrade it? I thought the `^` implies that any version above it is supported.

Comment: `^17` does **not** include `18.3.0` (if it did, why would they include `^16` _and_ `^17`?) - have a play with e.g. https://semver.npmjs.com/ if you're unfamiliar with semver.

Comment: Note that Git is not really relevant here. Git will store your files in commits, but Git itself has no influence over which version of npm is required or used.

Answer (score 0):

I forced the downgrade to `$ sudo npm install -g node@17.0.0 --force`

```
$ node -v
v17.0.0
$ cd lightweight-charts/
$ npm run build

> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 build
> npm-run-all tsc rollup bundle-dts

sh: line 1: npm-run-all: command not found
$ npm install npm-run-all
npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

added 657 packages, and audited 658 packages in 1m

148 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

5 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.

$ npm run build

> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 build
> npm-run-all tsc rollup bundle-dts


> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 tsc
> ttsc -p tsconfig.prod.json


> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 rollup
> rollup -c rollup.config.js

Building version: 4.0.0-dev+202206211052

./lib/prod/src/index.js → ./dist/lightweight-charts.esm.development.js...
created ./dist/lightweight-charts.esm.development.js in 608ms

./lib/prod/src/standalone.js → ./dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.development.js...
created ./dist/lightweight-charts.standalone.development.js in 474ms

> lightweight-charts@4.0.0 bundle-dts
> tsc --noEmit --allowJs dts-config.js && dts-bundle-generator --config dts-config.js

Compiling input files...
Processing lib/prod/src/index.d.ts
Writing lib/prod/src/index.d.ts -> dist/typings.d.ts
Checking generated files...
Done in 1.65s
```